# Matching observations across two string variables

Tags: database, dataframe, match, stata

I have two continuous indicators that are measured at the country-level:

1. GDP per capita
2. democracy score

I have two string variables that essentially use the same country coding system, such as AFG for Afghanistan. However, I only have 184 observations under the `country` variable for the GDP data, yet 249 observations under the `code` variable for the democracy_score data.

I would like to match GDP and democracy score data for observations where the data for both continuous indicators are complete. For instance, the data in the first row below is

```
"AFG" 2079.9219 "ABW" "0.813"
```

And I would like to match it with the democracy score data from the third row for observations where the country code is the same, "AFG".

```
"ALB" 13655.665 "AFG" "0.174"
```

And the correct data structure would be as follows for AFG:

```
country gdp_adj democracy_score 
"AFG" 2079.9219 "0.174"
```

Here is a data example:

```
dataex country gdp_adj code democracy_score
```

output:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str3 country float gdp_adj str3 code str5 democracy_score
"AFG" 2079.9219 "ABW" "0.813"
"AGO"  6602.424 "ADO" "#N/A" 
"ALB" 13655.665 "AFG" "0.174"
"ARE"  71782.16 "AIA" "#N/A" 
"ARG"  22071.75 "ALB" "0.576"
"ARM" 14317.553 "ANT" "#N/A" 
"ATG"  23035.66 "ARE" "0.232"
"AUS"  49379.09 "ARG" "0.632"
"AUT"  55806.44 "ARM" "0.496"
"AZE"  14442.04 "ASM" "#N/A" 
"BDI"  729.6584 "ATG" "#N/A" 
"BEL"  51977.18 "AUS" "0.861"
"BEN"  3156.439 "AUT" "0.852"
"BFA" 2110.0623 "AZE" "0.200"
"BGD"  5467.208 "BDI" "0.170"
"BGR" 23270.225 "BEL" "0.820"
"BHR"  49768.98 "BEN" "0.473"
"BHS" 35161.832 "BFA" "0.358"
"BIH" 14634.738 "BGD" "0.388"
"BLR" 19279.209 "BGR" "0.602"
"BLZ"  9028.552 "BHR" "0.190"
"BOL"  8528.749 "BHS" "0.688"
"BRA" 14685.128 "BIH" "0.399"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by stacking and reshaping back to wide:

```
destring democracy_score, replace ignore("#N/A")
stack country gdp_adj code democracy_score , into(country outcome) clear
reshape wide outcome, i(country) j(_stack)
rename (outcome1 outcome2) (gdp_adj democracy_score)
```

I converted the score from string to double under the assumption that you would want to do some analysis on it. If not, then you can `tostring` it back.

I also had to tweak the GDP storage to double to avoid some precision issues:

```
input str3 country double gdp_adj str3 code str5 democracy_score
```